# Is there any good textbook to learn about gauge theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Is there any good textbook to learn about gauge theory (transformations, invariance, etc.) and its uses in quantum mechanics?

EDIT: I am talking about things along the lines of the Aharonov-Bohm effect, Landau levels, particle in a ring with solenoid through it, etc.

Comment: To be clear, the gauge theory you want to learn about is like "particle on a ring with a solenoid through it" or "Aharonov-Bohm effect" in particle QM, not field theory like e.g. [Yang-Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory), do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  Yes.